# Can't start windows vista anymore

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have a windows vista and after i visited a website in firefox everything crashed and Many windows appeared saying :  stopped working...

Some of the programs names are : Internet explorer , run once wrapper , Dell dock, windows desktop manager, and many others

when I restart the computer I only get the same error windows in a black screen and the windows vista does not run

I did system restore but it is not finished successfuly

I can only work with the safe mode now

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Run on safe mode, and do a chkdsk /f restart your computer and see if that fixes your problem.

It sounds like you have a spyware problem that is stopping the boot config kick in place.

So once again if the chkdsk /f doesn't work check your start-up registry and see what's being started up that is unknown to you.

so in order to see what's being started up, go to your command promt, then go to msconfig and uncheck the unknown things on start up, and in services make sure you click on hide microsoft software, and uncheck all services that are unknown to you...

hope this helps

ps: you should run some type of virus scan and a spyware remover.

Answer (score 0):

Run a virus scan from safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

If System Restore doesn't work, you can do a Repair Install from the Vista DVD.